# Replacing text of links in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets-query, microsoft-excel

I have a bunch of links in cells in my google sheets. I want to replace all the text of them all just to say "LINK" so that when I click on them it's still hyperlinked to the correct site.

1. Is there a way to do this in bulk for existing links?
2. Is there a way to format links this way as default so whenever I paste a link in a cell it automatically writes "LINK" and hyperlinks it to the link I pasted?

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. There are a few ways to create a link in Google Sheets. One is just by entering an URL; another is by using the `HYPERLINK` formula. You said _I have a bunch of links in cells in my google sheets._ Would you please edit your question to describe EXACTLY how your "links" have been created? Would you also summarise your research, and outline your own attempts to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

yes and no ... you will still have to write the url somewhere and you will do it, for example, in column A of sheet1. The calculation to be inserted in a second sheet, the sheet where you don't want to see the URLs, will be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Sheet1!A1:A <>"",HYPERLINK(Sheet1!A1:A, "LINK"),""))
```